# Apache htaccess order of compression and cache

Tags: .htaccess

I have seen examples Apache htaccess file code where compression is before cache and visa versa.  Which is correct?  I use redbot.org quite a bit and it seems compressing after cache produces fewer issues.

Answer (score 0):

You may compress with gzip compression in this way:

```
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  <filesMatch ".(css|js|x?html?|php)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

To cache files, you could do this:

```
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch ".(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=216000, private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch ".(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=600, private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
```

To more informations, visit this page:
http://samaxes.com/2009/01/more-on-compressing-and-caching-your-site-with-htaccess/

Comment: Thank you for posting the information.  I understand the mechanics of gzip and cache.  My question was in which order should the be executed?  Gzip first or cache first?  I have seen it both ways on stack overflow and other sites.